# AS3 - Traversing XML?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm working with an XML file here, and somehow I cant get my head around it. It's been a loong day :P

So, I got my XMl file.

There is one main node, having 3 children. 
Each of these 3 children have another 10 children each.

So, There is some information stored only in the 3 "main" children, and I want to work my way up the parents till I find that information.

Example.

If I'm at one of the 10 children of the 3 children, I want to go up one level and check if I can find the value there. if not, go up another level and check again.

Guess this is really simple, but I just haven't worked enough with XML yet..

(I'm showing the XML in a Tree component. And I select my items there. If I'm at one of the branches I do get the information out (since each branch has the information I need), but when I'm at an item I cant get anything back from it's parent).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to create loop for 3 parent tags, then one loop for children tags.
Maybe this will give you an idea:

```
for each (var myparenttag:XML in myxmlobject.parenttag)
{
    for each (var mychildtag:XML in myparenttag)  
    {
        trace(mychildtag.someelementinchildtag);
        trace(mychildtag.@someattributeinchildtag);
        trace(myparenttag.somechilditem);
        trace(myparenttag.childtag[0]);
        trace(myparenttag.childtag[1]);
        trace(myparenttag.@attributeincurrentparenttag);
    }
}
```